# call sqlite query from separated class

Tags: android

i have some problems in my database... here the scenario

i want to make separated data base like this

**class 1** : declare the data base --> master.sqlite

**class 2** : declare the query toward the data base in class 1

**class 3** : call the query from class 2 and get the result

**in my class 1 i declare my database like this**

```
public class Database_Login extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static int iconPos;

private static String DB_NAME = "Master.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase loginDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

private static String DB_PATH;

public Database_Login(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + myContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/"; 
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } 

    catch (SQLiteException e){


    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    loginDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (loginDataBase != null)
        loginDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

**and in class 2 i declare like this**

```
public class Login{
public static int iconPos;

Database_Login login;
SQLiteDatabase loginDataBase;

public Login(Context context) {
    login = new Database_Login(context);
    loginDataBase = login.getReadableDatabase();
}

public boolean cekLogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    login.openDataBase();
    loginDataBase = login.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = loginDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserName=? AND Password=?", new String[] { username, password});
    if (mCursor != null) {
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    login.close();
    return false;
}

public String UserType(String username) throws SQLException{
    login.openDataBase();
    loginDataBase = login.getReadableDatabase();
    String UserType = "";
    Cursor mCursor = loginDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT UserType FROM tblUser WHERE UserName=?", new String[] { username });
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
        UserType = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("UserType"));
        return UserType;
    }
    login.close();
    return UserType;
}

public int checkIcon() {
    switch (iconPos) {
    case 0:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_help;
        break;
    case 1:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_good;
        break;
    case 2:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_labels;
        break;
    case 3:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_email;
        break;
    case 4:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad;
        break;
    case 5:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_search;
        break;
    case 6:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_cloud;
        break;
    case 7:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_camera;
        break;
    case 8:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_video;
        break;
    case 9:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_group;
        break;
    case 10:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_import_export;
        break;
    case 11:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_help;
        break;
    case 12:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_about;
        break;
    case 13:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_settings;
        break;
    case 14:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad;
        break;
    case 15:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_cloud;
        break;
    case 16:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_camera;
        break;
    case 17:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_video;
        break;
    case 18:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_import_export;
        break;
    case 19:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_about;
        break;
    case 20:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_good;
        break;
    case 21:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad;
        break;
    case 22:
        iconPos = R.drawable.ic_action_cloud;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return iconPos;
}
```

}

**and in class 3 i just call the class 2 method**

but when i run it, the log cat said that no tblUser found...

how i supposed to do to make my database work???

thx for your help...

Comment: First of all check your db is copied in to data/data or not.

Comment: Where is your logcat error? Do post logcat error also.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have added the table after first install. When you install the application for debug it doesn't copy the database from assets again. To get the latest database you will have to uninstall the application and have a fresh install.